# How to proxy nmap and dns resolution of nmap

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, nmap, tor

How to use nmap and dns resolution of nmap over proxy?

I tried proxychains, but for dns resolution it doesn't work, it's known bug as I read on some forums. It works well without dns_proxy feature in proxychains config. But I need to proxy dns resolution requests.

```
sudo proxychains nmap -T4 -sV -Pn -A --reason -v scanme.nmap.org
```

I tried proxychains4 (or proxychains-ng), but with nmap it does scanning and send all the packets synchronously, so for example for scan of one host it's needed to wait for 30 min or ever longer. So it's not the option, but it works well.

```
sudo proxychains4 nmap -T4 -sV -Pn -A --reason -v scanme.nmap.org
```

I tried just like this with inside nmap proxy function:

```
sudo nmap --proxy socks4://127.0.0.1:9050 -T4 -sV -Pn -A --reason -v scanme.nmap.org
```

But does it dns resolution requests over the tor proxy 127.0.0.1:9050 or only scan? It seems it doesn't.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo nmap --proxy socks4://127.0.0.1:9050 --dns-servers 8.8.8.8 -T4 -sV -Pn -A --reason -v scanme.nmap.org
```

You can specify the domain name to use by `nmap` using the option `--dns-servers`. The problem here is that the default DNS server is your router which will have a private address , so your DNS server is hidden from the internet . By using `--dns-servers` I just tell the command `nmap` to use the Google's public domain name. (private addresses like 192.168.1.0/24 are not routable.)

Comment: You can specify the domain name to use by nmap using the option --dns-servers . The probleme here is that the default DNS server is your router witch will have a private address , so your DNS server is hidden from the internet . by using --dsn-servers I just tell the commande nmap to use the google's public domain name. (private address like 192.168.1.0/24 are not routable)

Comment: I've copied your comment back in to the Answer so it's easy for people to read. Now we can both delete our comments and the Answer stands tall by itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is my setup and `proxychains4` is working fine.

---

First, I have tor service configured and running on port 9050.

Second, this is the proxychains config (`/etc/proxychains4.conf`) I have (comment out an socks4 lines):

```
socks5  127.0.0.1 9050
```

And this is the exact same namp command I ran just now (took 5 minutes to complete). Note that the `sudo` comes after the `proxychains4` command.

```
❯ proxychains4 sudo nmap -T4 -sV -Pn -A --reason -v scanme.nmap.org
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains4.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-01-09 00:08 AEDT
NSE: Loaded 151 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 00:08
Completed NSE at 00:08, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 00:08
Completed NSE at 00:08, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 00:08
Completed NSE at 00:08, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 00:08
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 00:08, 0.52s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 00:08
Scanning scanme.nmap.org (45.33.32.156) [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 45.33.32.156
Discovered open port 443/tcp on 45.33.32.156
Discovered open port 8080/tcp on 45.33.32.156
Discovered open port 5060/tcp on 45.33.32.156
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 45.33.32.156
Discovered open port 31337/tcp on 45.33.32.156
Discovered open port 9929/tcp on 45.33.32.156
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 00:08, 2.82s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Initiating Service scan at 00:08
Scanning 7 services on scanme.nmap.org (45.33.32.156)
Service scan Timing: About 71.43% done; ETC: 00:11 (0:00:44 remaining)
Completed Service scan at 00:10, 117.24s elapsed (7 services on 1 host)
Initiating OS detection (try #1) against scanme.nmap.org (45.33.32.156)
Retrying OS detection (try #2) against scanme.nmap.org (45.33.32.156)
Initiating Traceroute at 00:10
Completed Traceroute at 00:10, 3.19s elapsed
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 11 hosts. at 00:10
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 11 hosts. at 00:10, 1.13s elapsed
NSE: Script scanning 45.33.32.156.
Initiating NSE at 00:10
Completed NSE at 00:11, 48.07s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 00:11
Completed NSE at 00:12, 60.07s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 00:12
Completed NSE at 00:12, 0.00s elapsed
Nmap scan report for scanme.nmap.org (45.33.32.156)
Host is up, received user-set (0.21s latency).
Other addresses for scanme.nmap.org (not scanned): 2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe18:bb2f
Not shown: 992 closed ports
Reason: 992 resets
PORT      STATE    SERVICE    REASON         VERSION
22/tcp    open     ssh        syn-ack ttl 52 OpenSSH 6.6.1p1 Ubuntu 2ubuntu2.13 (Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0)
| ssh-hostkey:
|   1024 ac:00:a0:1a:82:ff:cc:55:99:dc:67:2b:34:97:6b:75 (DSA)
|   2048 20:3d:2d:44:62:2a:b0:5a:9d:b5:b3:05:14:c2:a6:b2 (RSA)
|   256 96:02:bb:5e:57:54:1c:4e:45:2f:56:4c:4a:24:b2:57 (ECDSA)
|_  256 33:fa:91:0f:e0:e1:7b:1f:6d:05:a2:b0:f1:54:41:56 (ED25519)
25/tcp    filtered smtp       no-response
80/tcp    open     http       syn-ack ttl 64 Apache httpd 2.4.7 ((Ubuntu))
|_http-favicon: Unknown favicon MD5: 156515DA3C0F7DC6B2493BD5CE43F795
| http-methods:
|_  Supported Methods: GET HEAD POST OPTIONS
|_http-server-header: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
|_http-title: Go ahead and ScanMe!
443/tcp   open     tcpwrapped syn-ack ttl 64
5060/tcp  open     tcpwrapped syn-ack ttl 64
8080/tcp  open     tcpwrapped syn-ack ttl 64
9929/tcp  open     nping-echo syn-ack ttl 53 Nping echo
31337/tcp open     tcpwrapped syn-ack ttl 52
Aggressive OS guesses: HP P2000 G3 NAS device (93%), Linux 2.6.32 (92%), Linux 2.6.32 - 3.1 (92%), Ubiquiti AirMax NanoStation WAP (Linux 2.6.32) (92%), Linux 3.7 (92%), Linux 2.6.32 - 3.13 (92%), Linux 3.0 - 3.2 (92%), Linux 3.3 (92%), Infomir MAG-250 set-top box (91%), Linux 3.1 (91%)
No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).
Uptime guess: 11.213 days (since Tue Dec 28 19:06:04 2021)
Network Distance: 12 hops
TCP Sequence Prediction: Difficulty=256 (Good luck!)
IP ID Sequence Generation: All zeros
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel

TRACEROUTE (using port 199/tcp)
HOP RTT       ADDRESS
1   ...
2   70.32 ms  REDACTED
3   171.80 ms REDACTED
4   171.83 ms REDACTED
5   251.96 ms REDACTED
6   252.09 ms REDACTED
7   252.11 ms REDACTED
8   252.13 ms REDACTED
9   252.15 ms REDACTED
10  252.20 ms 38.142.11.154
11  252.22 ms if-1-4.csw5-fnc1.linode.com (173.230.159.81)
12  252.25 ms scanme.nmap.org (45.33.32.156)

NSE: Script Post-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 00:12
Completed NSE at 00:12, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 00:12
Completed NSE at 00:12, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 00:12
Completed NSE at 00:12, 0.00s elapsed
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 240.81 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 1234 (56.044KB) | Rcvd: 1078 (45.547KB)
```